# To view web page in webview

Tags: objective-c

I have, for exa, "Facebook" button in `SocialWeb.xib`. I want that if user clicks on that button, the webview, defined in another `View.xib`, should view Facebook page. What is the code for `View.xib` that I must write?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should coordinate this event via your controller, anyway. Can't say exactly what to do without your code. Try this

```
//Load web view data
NSString *strWebsiteUlr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your.url"];

//Create a URL object.
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strWebsiteUlr];

//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

//Load the request in the UIWebView.
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

Comment: of course, you should load this request from the controller, which maintains your webView

Comment: I have written the same in viewDidLoad, but I have found bug in main.m.

Comment: Don't even know for what reason you should change anything in main.m ))